# Problem in my custom setInterval() function in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, web, try-catch, settimeout, setinterval

Here I made a custom setInterval function but it is not working as desired.

```
function interval(func,ti,f){
if(f==0||f==undefined){
    try{                  //calls the function provided as argument.
        func.call();
    }
    catch(err){            //if error occurs
        alert('error occured!'); //edited       
        throw new Error("error occured!!");//edited

    }
    setTimeout(interval(func,ti,f),ti);
   }
}
```

The main idea behind this is that the user calls the function somewhat like this:

```
interval(()=>{
   console.log('hello world');
 },10000);
```

Since I'm not passing the value of **f** so it is **undefined**
so it satisfies and enters the if statement. Now when `try{}` calls the function, it executes. The problem is that I am calling the SetInterval function by passing arguments as the function `interval()` and `ti` which is the time in milliseconds.

So it should call the function `interval()` after time `ti` but it is not doing so.

Comment: You should call it like `setTimeout(function() { interval(func,ti,f); }, ti);` as the `setTimeout` will call the given function after the required amount of time will pass

Comment: You are calling the function and assigning what it returns to the timeout....You are not calling the function when the timeout runs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`setTimeout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout#Parameters) requires a function, you are passing the value of a function call.

---

Change

```
setTimeout(interval(func,ti,f),ti);
```

to

```
setTimeout(() => interval(func,ti,f),ti);
```